# Water Consumption Tracker Cant Add Numbers

Tags: python

I'm doing a college project and can't get this code to work. It works fine up until the end when I get the error code.

```
File "c:\users\___\waterconsumptiontracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    DWC = (a + b + c + d + e)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Can anyone help? I'm very new to coding!

```
ShowerInput = input("Did you take a shower today? Y/N")

if(ShowerInput == ("Y") or ("y") or ("Yes") or ("yes")):
    ShowerTime = input("How long was your shower in minutes?")
a = ShowerTime * 15

Handwash = int(input("How many times did you wash you hands today?"))
b = Handwash * 3

BrushTeeth = int(input("How many times did you brush your teeth today?"))

if(BrushTeeth > 0):
    Tap = input("Do you turn off the tap while brushing? Y/N")
    if Tap == ("Y"):
        Brushing = (2)
    else:
        Brushing = (8)
c = BrushTeeth * Brushing

DrinkingWater = int(input("How many litres of water did you drink today?"))
d = DrinkingWater

Toilet = int(input("How many times did you flush the toilet today?"))
e = Toilet * 15

DWC = (a + b + c + d + e)

print("Your Daily Water Consumption today was:")
print(DWC)
```

Comment: You forgot to turn ShowerTime into an int.  So you are multiplying a string by 15 getting 15 concatenated copies.

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful stuff! Definitely a mistake I wont be making in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You forgot to turn ShowerTime into an int. So you are multiplying a string by 15 getting 15 concatenated copies.

You can do an `int(input())` when you ask for ShowerTime.

```
ShowerInput = input("Did you take a shower today? Y/N")

if(ShowerInput == ("Y") or ("y") or ("Yes") or ("yes")):
    ShowerTime = int(input("How long was your shower in minutes?")) # int(input here
a = ShowerTime * 15

Handwash = int(input("How many times did you wash you hands today?"))
b = Handwash * 3

BrushTeeth = int(input("How many times did you brush your teeth today?"))

if(BrushTeeth > 0):
    Tap = input("Do you turn off the tap while brushing? Y/N") 
    if Tap == ("Y"):
        Brushing = (2)
    else:
        Brushing = (8)
c = BrushTeeth * Brushing

DrinkingWater = int(input("How many litres of water did you drink today?"))
d = DrinkingWater

Toilet = int(input("How many times did you flush the toilet today?"))
e = Toilet * 15

DWC = (a + b + c + d + e)

print("Your Daily Water Consumption today was:")
print(a + b + c + d + e)
```

Comment: Did you just copy my comment and use my suggestion to create an answer?

Comment: @RufusVS Sorry, I forgot to do an blackquote, and I was already typing the answer to the question, but you commented. so, I thought it was a nice comment, so I decided to put your comment in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was definitely staring at it for too long and couldnt realise that it was that simple!

Comment: @RossO'Brien Happy to help! please accept it by clicking the check mark.